# Is it possible to send a byte array in a JMS message in jmeter by mapmessage?

Tags: arrays, string, jmeter

I would like to know if someone has been able to send a byte array in the jmeter by mapmessage without the output being a string

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMS Publisher documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher) it is possible:

> The Object message is implemented and works as follow:
>
> - Put the JAR that contains your object and its dependencies in jmeter_home/lib/ folder
> - Serialize your object as XML using XStream
> - Either put result in a file suffixed with .txt or .obj or put XML content directly in Text Area
>
> Note that if message is in a file, replacement of properties will not occur while it will if you use Text Area.

If it is not something you're looking for - you can always directly call [BytesMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html) class functions, i.e. [writeBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html#writeBytes-byte:A-) from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)