# in JMeter, how to send a 4 byte message to a JMS publisher

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

Don't think this has been asked this specifically.

I have to run a performance test on a application that consumes from a ActiveMQ topic. The sampler needs to publish 4 Bytes of data in to the topic which usually be the format of (if you look at the hex value) 0x006403D6.

If you translate them in to decimals, they will be

0x03D6 = 00000011 11010110 ==> 982 ==> 03,D6 ==> 03, 214 ==> 3,214
0x0064 = 00000000 01100100 ==> 100 ==> 00,64 ==> 00, 100 ==> 0,100

So the above example the 4 bytes will be [0,100,3,214].

To get this done I have used a JMSPublisher.

The below is the configuration:

[image]

Since I have to send a byte stream I thought to use a ByteMessage from a file.
[image]

I tried above with different content in the file in the configuration. But non would give me [0,100,3,214].

It looks like JMeter does convert the text, characters in to byte values. So If I have a empty file the topic will reeve 0 and application will consider it as [0,0,0,0] (Application considers only the first 4 bytes)

If I have ???? in the text file I get [63,63,63,63] (As ? ==> 00111111 ==> 63 in Decimal). 
But If I have to get the first byte a 0, I am unable to get that through? As there is no character I could found to represent 0.

May be There is a better way of doing this. Please advise ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [JMS Sampler JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/sampler/JMSSampler.html#setContent-java.lang.String-), the `setContent()` function accepts String only so there is no way to pass bytes to this as JMeter will treat them as a simple string.

However as per [JMS Publisher documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher) you should be able to send whatever you want **given the object is serialised by [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/)**

> The Object message is implemented and works as follow:
>
> - Put the JAR that contains your object and its dependencies in jmeter_home/lib/ folder
> - Serialize your object as XML using XStream
> - Either put result in a file suffixed with .txt or .obj or put XML content directly in Text Area
>
> Note that if message is in a file, replacement of properties will not occur while it will if you use Text Area.

Also be aware that you can always switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and use [ByteMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html) class from [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code.

Comment: Thanks .... I have seen this answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359111/is-it-possible-to-send-a-byte-array-in-a-jms-message-in-jmeter-by-mapmessage. But not sure what I needs to do in the above steps. In my case above, If I have to send the 4 bytes to the topic in Java, Id do javax.jms.MessageProducer..send(javax.jms.BytesMessage). Does that mean, I have to place javax.jms.* jars in jmeter_home/lib/ folder ? If so I have to serialize javax.jms.BytesMessage using XStream and generate a xml and place in the text area ?

Comment: I tried to serialize javax.jms.BytesMessage using XStream and generate a xml.  The output was not the one I expected. 
 It generated a `<org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage>`

Comment: You need to serialize your 4 bytes **as XML** and paste this XML into the Text Area

Comment: Thanks @dmitri-t. That didn't worked either. When I convert my 4 bytes it looks like this. `<byte-array>AGQD1g==</byte-array>` , when I paste this in the text area, and publish the JMS, my application didnt liked that. It says  `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.BytesMessage`. So as I said erlier, i need to send the javax.jms.BytesMessage, Is this somethig to do with the Initial Context factory ? . I'm using `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` there ....

Comment: do you have a sample code  to serialize your 4 bytes as XML, which I can use?

Comment: I figured that out from this http://x-stream.github.io/converters.html site that , when you serialize a byte[] from xstream you get smoething like `<byte-array>AHiEFiEABQ==</byte-array>`. IN my case I got `<byte-array>AGQD1g==</byte-array>`. But my appliation is failing to translate the message coming from ActiveMQ as `javax,jms.ByteMessage` .... I see `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.BytesMessage` in the log. How can we make sure that we send a `javax.jms.ByteMessage` ?